# Working Poetry project with private dependencies inside Docker

Tags: python, gcloud, python-poetry, google-artifact-registry, python-keyring

I have a Python library hosted in [Google Cloud Platform Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry). Besides, I have a Python project, using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), that depends on the library.

This is my project file `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "Test"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "Test project."
authors = [
    "Me <me@mycompany.com>"
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8,<4.0"
mylib = "0.1.1"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
"keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth" = "^1.1.0"
keyring = "^23.9.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.1.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my-lib"
url = "https://us-east4-python.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/my-lib/simple/"
secondary = true
```

To enable using my private repository, I installed [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) and authenticated with my credentials. So when I run this command, I see proper results, like this:

```bash
$ gcloud auth list
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
...
*       <my-account>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
...
```

Additionally, I'm using [Python keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) togheter with [keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth](https://pypi.org/project/keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth/), as you can see in the project file.

So, with this setup, I can run `poetry install`, the dependency gets downloaded from my private artifact registry, using the authentication from GCP.

---

The issue comes when I try to apply the same principles inside a Docker container.

I created a Docker file like this:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.3
FROM python:3.9

# Install Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH "${PATH}:/root/.local/bin"

# Install Google Cloud SDK CLI
ARG GCLOUD_VERSION="401.0.0-linux-x86_64"
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-cli-${GCLOUD_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf google-cloud-cli-*.tar.gz && \
    ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet && \
    rm google-cloud-cli-*.tar.gz
ENV PATH "${PATH}:/google-cloud-sdk/bin"

# install Google Artifact Rrgistry keyring integration
RUN pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/run/secrets/GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
RUN gcloud auth list
RUN keyring --list-backends

WORKDIR /app

# copy Poetry project files and install dependencies
COPY ./.env* ./
COPY ./pyproject.toml ./poetry.lock* ./
RUN poetry install

# copy source files
COPY ./app /app/app

# run the program
CMD poetry run python -m app.main
```

As you can see, I injected the Google credentials file, [following this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account). This works. I used Docker BuildKit secrets, as exposed [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information) (security concerns are not a matter of this question). So, when I try to build the image, I got an authentication error (`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is properly set pointing to a valid key file):

```bash
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker image build --secret id=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,src=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} -t app-test .

...
#19 66.68 <c1>Source (my-lib):</c1> Authorization error accessing https://us-east4-python.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/my-lib/simple/mylib/
#19 68.21
#19 68.21   RuntimeError
#19 68.21
#19 68.22   Unable to find installation candidates for mylib (0.1.1)
...
```

If I execute, line by line, all the commands in the Dockerfile, using the same Google credentials key file outside Docker, I got it working.

I even tried to debug inside the image, not executing `poetry install`, nor `poetry run...` commands, and I saw this, if it helps to debug:

```bash
# gcloud auth list
                  Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       <my-account>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

```bash
# keyring --list-backends
keyrings.gauth.GooglePythonAuth (priority: 9)
keyring.backends.chainer.ChainerBackend (priority: -1)
keyring.backends.fail.Keyring (priority: 0)
```

Finally, I even tried following this approach: [Using Keyring on headless Linux systems in a Docker container](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/main/README.rst#using-keyring-on-headless-linux-systems), with the same results:

```bash
# apt update
...
# apt install -y gnome-keyring
...
# dbus-run-session -- sh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/root/.cache/keyring-MEY1T1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/root/.cache/keyring-MEY1T1/ssh
# poetry install
...
  • Installing mylib (0.1.1): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for mylib (0.1.1)

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:103 in choose_for
       99│
      100│             links.append(link)
      101│
      102│         if not links:
    → 103│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
      104│
      105│         # Get the best link
      106│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
      107│
...
```

I even tried following the advices of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528100/how-to-unlock-gnome-keyring-on-debian-headless-wsl-2-and-make-it-work-in-pytho). No success.

`gcloud` CLI works inside the container, testing other commands. My guess is that the integration with Keyring is not working properly, but I don't know how to debug it.

**How can I get my dependency resolved inside a Docker container?**

Comment: Maybe some clues there: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/search?q=google+artifact+registry&type=issues

Comment: thanks @sinoroc! the issues mentioned in this search happen inside and outside Docker, and are previous to Poetry 1.2.x, which solve all of them. my issue is focused in making work inside Docker something that works outside

Comment: Is it really necessary to install and run Poetry inside the Docker container (even if just to build a Docker image, i.e. in the `Dockerfile`)? I always recommend to not run Poetry at all in Docker containers. Typically I recommend preparing a wheelhouse and mount this wheelhouse in the Docker container (or `COPY` the wheelhouse in the `Dockerfile`). But well, it can not fit all use cases for sure, so maybe in your case you can not go around using Poetry in Docker, I do not know.

Comment: your option is legit, but in my projects, typically the build of the image is performed in a CI environment, which commonly uses Docker. so it looks like the problem is the same. anyway, I think it is pretty common using Poetry inside Docker, there are even official Docker images using it.

Comment: I am not convinced... All use cases of Poetry inside Docker I have seen so far were misguided. I really encourage you to eliminate poetry from the Docker images and containers if you can. This should eliminate a lot of pain points. The typical path to go around it is to go through a "wheelhouse" instead (exporting the lockfile to a pip `requirements.txt` file can help), and then feed that wheelhouse to the Docker image and/or container. Poetry is a dev tool, and dev tools do not normally belong in Docker. -- But of course I do not know enough about your actual use case, so I might be wrong...

Comment: @sinroc I have a comment: if I execute the build of my Docker image in a CI environment like Travis, which uses Docker behind the scenes, I need to be authenticated to generate the `requirements.txt` file, using Poetry, during the process. I guess I would have the same issue, that is that the integration between Keyring and `gcloud` would not work in that environment. said so, it looks like the only workaround would be adding `requirements.txt` file to my VCS, which I would rather avoid. it looks I'm in a chicken-and-egg situation... seriously, nobody tried to follow a similar approach?

Comment: I see... anyway whether or not it is a good approach, it should work; on this we can agree. Sadly I do not know how to help. Maybe either ask Google support or ask the questions in Poetry ticket tracker (or GitHub discussions or Discord).

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72214875)

Comment: Hey @logoff - we're running into a similar issue - have you found any more details, or hopefully a solution?

Comment: @AmitGal I hope my answer works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218763/1213934

Comment: Thanks a lot @logoff! That's great. At the moment we circled back and trying to solve it via publishing the package in a github repo which seems to work as well. But it's really good to have this as solution - thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution that worked in my use case.

There are two main parts:

1. Installing [keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth](https://pypi.org/project/keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth/) as [a Poetry plugin](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/plugins/#the-self-add-command), using this command:

```
poetry self add keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
```

2. Authenticating inside the container using a [service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys):

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json
```

In my case, I use [BuildKit secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret) to handle it.

Then, for instance, the Dockerfile would like this:

```
FROM python:3.9

# Install Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH "${PATH}:/root/.local/bin"

# install Google Artifact Registry tools for Python as a Poetry plugin
RUN poetry self add keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth

# Install Google Cloud SDK CLI
ARG GCLOUD_VERSION="413.0.0-linux-x86_64"
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-cli-${GCLOUD_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf google-cloud-cli-*.tar.gz && \
    ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet && \
    rm google-cloud-cli-*.tar.gz
ENV PATH "${PATH}:/google-cloud-sdk/bin"

# authenticate with gcloud using a BuildKit secret
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=gac.json \
    gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/run/secrets/gac.json

COPY ./pyproject.toml ./poetry.lock* /
RUN poetry install

# deauthenticate with gcloud once the dependencies are already installed to clean the image
RUN gcloud auth revoke --all

COPY ./app /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["whatever", "command", "you", "use"]
```

And the Docker build command, providing the secret:

```bash
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker image build \
        --secret id=gac.json,src=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} \
        -t ${YOUR_TAG} .
```

And with Docker Compose, a similar approach:

```yaml
services:
  yourapp:
    build:
      context: .
      secrets:
        - key.json
    image: yourapp:yourtag
    ...
```

```
COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker compose up --build
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}` in your dockerfile command but you have not defined it anywhere in the Dockerfile using ENV or ARG.

For example in your Dockerfile in this section

```
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-cli-${GCLOUD_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
```

You are using the variable `GCLOUD_VERSION` and you have defined it in your Dockerfile over here

```
ARG GCLOUD_VERSION="401.0.0-linux-x86_64"
```

So when you are using the variable in this line:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/run/secrets/GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

You need to define it as ENV **in the Dockerfile**.

I hope this helps!

Comment: hanks for your answer. this is not the issue, because as I stated in the question, `gcloud` is correctly authenticated. if there would have been an issue with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var, this would have been not possible, which is not the case. this var is used from BuildKit, and it's exported before calling the image build command.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that `poetry` can't get the credentials from the keyring as it doesn't have `keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth` installed, and it can't install `keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth` because it fails to install the private package. To solve this, you need to bootstrap or pre-install `keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth`. [`tox` suffers from a similar issue, but has a documented method to deal with it.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-python-tools#usage-with-tox)

The documentation for `poetry` notes a similar issue for Azure in the second info box under the [Configuring Credentials](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#configuring-credentials) section. However, Azure solves the bootstrapping issue it by having a package that pre-seeds new virtual environments with the necessary packages for authentication. I couldn't find an equivalent for GCE, so that's not an option unless you develop one yourself.

Alternatively, since you are including a lock file with your project you could try exploiting the dependency groups option to get poetry to setup the virtual environment and install `keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth` before installing everything else. I haven't tried this as I don't have a GCE or Azure account, but I figured I would share it on the off-chance it works:

Add the following section to `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry.group.seed.dependencies]
keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth = "^1.1.1"
```

Then use the following in your `Dockerfile` to replace your current authentication and install sections:

```
# copy Poetry project files and install dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./.env* ./
COPY ./pyproject.toml ./poetry.lock* ./

# install Google Artifact Registry keyring integration
RUN poetry install --only seed
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/run/secrets/GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
RUN gcloud auth list
RUN poetry run keyring --list-backends

RUN poetry install
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer. I tried your method, using the pre-seed option to install Google Keyring, but unfortunately it produced the same result: `Authorization error accessing...` my private repo. anyway, I will follow this thread, because it looks an explanation for my issues. however, I still don't get why this works outside Docker...

Comment: Did you get that error when doing the seed install, or doing the main install?

Comment: the seed install worked. and I got the same error doing the normal `poetry install`, trying to retrieve `mylib`, with the same error than in the exposed in the question. in fact, before applying your proposal, I was getting a local list of Keyring backends, as showed in the question, so I think this is not the actual issue. I'm not sure.